# Record 25 fps video using Flutter's camera plugin

Tags: android, ios, flutter, video, camera

I am using [Flutter's Camera Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) to capture video. I strictly need the videos to be recorded at 25 fps. How can I achieve this?

Here is the starting code from [Flutter's camera example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/example/lib/main.dart).

Comment: any news on this? I also need to control the recording frame rate

Comment: Any solution of reducing fps while recording video??